# Run javascript after redirect to click a button

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

So what I am trying to do seems simple enough, but I haven't found a way to do it.

I want to load a webpage that has a post request on it. I would just like to click the submit button using javascript, which submits the form and loads the reply. The button has an id of "buttonSubmit". I can load the webpage (let's say that it is https://www.somepage.com/form.aspx , and I do not have access to the server it runs on).

If I load the page in the browser, enter into the console, and type the following script, it works:

```
document.getElementById('buttonSubmit').click();
```

So I need to put that into a webpage that I can run off of my machine, so the page will load the reply to the post request.

I tried to write an html page which has the javacript:

```
window.location.href='https://www.somepage.com/form.aspx';
document.getElementById('buttonSubmit').click();
```

However, this code is not going to work, since after the URL changes, it is not going to execute the next line of code.

So next thing I tried was to load the URL in an iframe and try to run the script on it.

However, that doesn't work, per the following page:

[Error trying to access a iframe in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446106/error-trying-to-access-a-iframe-in-javascript)

Whenever I try to access an element inside the iframe I get an error that it is an unsafe operation or that there was an error.

What is the best way to do this? There must be a way to get this to work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can't with JavaScript alone. It would be a huge security issue if you could. Load the url on the server and serve a copy of it as your own page.

Comment: exactly what Juhana said, it would be a security breach to that server

Comment: Loading some page and clicking some button on it looks more like some automation work. In that case you can look at tools like Selenium and Test Driver.

Comment: @Juhana, how would I do that? I am new to this, so a walkthrough or a link to a guide would be much appreciated :) Thank you.

Comment: Or any workaround really to this problem. Thanks!